# How to test if an object is a vector in R

Tags: r

I want to test if an object is a vector in R. I'm confused as to why

```
is.vector(c(0.1))
```

returns TRUE and so does

```
is.vector(0.1)
```

I would like it to return false when it is just a number and true when it is a vector. Can anyone offer any help on this please?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: A number in R is a vector with one element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in R there doesn't exist a single number or string alone. They are vectors of length 1. Or embedded in some more complex structures.

`is.vector(c(0.1))` and `is.vector(0.1)` are in R absolutely identical.

That is also the reason, why `length("this is a string/character")` returns `1` - because `length()` in this case measures the number of elements in the vector.

And you see it if you type `"this is a string/character"` into R console:
It returns `[1] "this is a string/character"` - the `[1]` indicates: vector of length 1.

So you have to do `nchar("this is a string/character")` to get the length of the first element - the charater string - returning `26`.

```
nchar(c("this is a string/character", "and this another string"))
## [1] 26 23
## nchar is vectorized as you see ...
```

This is an important difference to Python, where strings and numbers can stand alone.
So `len("this")` returns 4 in Python. `len(["this"])` however 1 (1 element in list, thus length of list is 1).

Answer (score 2):

As already mentioned by @RHertel, R considers `c(0.1)` a vector of length 1. You may want to test for `length` as well. E.g.

```
> x <- 1
> y <- 1:2
> is.vector(x) & length(x) > 1
[1] FALSE
> is.vector(y) & length(y) > 1
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Should be used with care. If a vector has any attribute `is.vector()` evaluates to `FALSE`. `y <- factor(y); is.vector(y)`

Comment: But if it is about type, `c(0.1)` and `0.1` are absolutely identical in R - and both are vectors.

Comment: `is.vector(list(b = 1:10, iris))`